# I got a error message tryinh to install Prokka

Tags: perl, installation

I am trying to install a software called prokka(http://www.vicbioinformatics.com/software.prokka.shtml)
But i got a error in installation.

I tried install as indicated  via git hub clone:
and got this:

Can't locate XML/Simple.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::Simple module) (@INC contains: /home/paulo/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/paulo/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2 /home/paulo/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/paulo/anaconda3/lib/5.26.2 .) at /home/paulo/prokka/bin/prokka line 29.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/paulo/prokka/bin/prokka line 29.

I tried to install the XML with:

```
sudo cpan install
```

But not worked to.

I also installed successively all other dependencies as asked but seems not work.

Then I tried with conda and got this:

> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while
>   installing package 'bioconda::perl-algorithm-diff-1.1903-pl526_2'.
>   Rolling back transaction: done [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/home/paulo/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/Algorithm' ()

Now I dont know what else to do.

Any help?

Thank you by your time.

Paulo

Comment: PS- I tried to install bioconda::perl-algorithm-diff-1.1903-pl526_2 separatelly, but didn't work too.

Comment: Have you looked at `/home/paulo/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/Algorithm` and who owns it?  A hunch might be that you used `sudo` to install part of that package as `root` but under your user, and now your user can't modify.

Comment: I try this:  ls -l /home/paulo/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/Algorithmls: cannot access '/home/paulo/anaconda3/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/Algorithm': No such file or directory

Comment: maybe it's `5.26.2` or a prior path component that has a permissions issue?

Comment: probably you meant to install with `cpan install [MODULE]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a conda update all, crate a env prokka and it was done.
Thank you for your help and time guys.

Paulo

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to install the XML with: sudo cpan install But not worked to.

It would be helpful to know exactly how this failed. What error messages you got.

You don't say what kind of system you're trying to work on, but if you're using a Linux distribution, it's almost certain that there's a pre-build package for XML::Simple. Try `sudo dnf install Perl-XML-Simple` on a Red Hat-based system and `sudo apt-get install libxml-simple-perl` on a Debian-based system.